# An example of a residually-finite group which does not have an infinite residually-$p$ subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory

1. Does there exist a residually-finite group $G$, preferably finitely generated, such that $\widehat{G}$, the profinite completion of $G$, contains an infinite pro-$p$ subgroup, but $G$ does not contain an infinite residually-$p$ subgroup?

**Update:** Following the comments below I decided to remove my second question. I was trying to understand the following. The image of $G$ in $\widehat{G}$ is dense, but it might intersect $P$, the Sylow pro-$p$ subgroup of $\widehat{G}$, trivially. However, in the examples I have in mind you can still "recognize" $P$ from $G$. So the very imprecise question is how "bad" can it be? How much more you can get in $P$ compared to any pro-$p$ completion of a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Your group would have to be torsion

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg why?

Comment: Infinite cyclic groups are residually p for all p

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg  I knew I would have to add more conditions to make it interesting, but I just didn't know which ones. :-)

Comment: @YCor I think you misread the question. It is not the profinite completion that does not contain..., but the original group.

Comment: Now $G=\mathbf{Z}$ is an example for 2, so certainly 2 does not really make the question more interesting.

Comment: @YCor, you are right. I keep messing it up. I tried to reformulate it again. Intuitively, I am looking for a group where the profinite completion has a big Sylow pro-$p$ subgroup, but you cannot "see" this pro-$p$ subgroup in the original group.

Comment: Now in 2 again $G$ has to be torsion.

Comment: @YCor, yes you are right again. I'll look at it again tomorrow, when I am less tired.

Comment: @YCor I removed my question and explained what I was trying to ask and failed.